# jQuery conflict in the product view page

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, jquery

I implement **jquery lazyloads** to load product images on scrolling..

I added the following codes to `view.phtml`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.lazyload.js?v=1.9.7'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function() {
 $("img.lazy").lazyload({
     effect : "fadeIn"
 });
});

</script>

<?php foreach ($galleryCollection as $_image): ?>
        <img class="lazy products" data-original="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->keepFrame(false)->resize(426,700); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true);?>" />                                       
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The out put is fine as i expected.Images are loading on scroll.
**BUT**
Unable to click the magento view option button.
**Code for view option button click is below.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Event.observe($('show_bundle_options'),"click",function(){
    $('bundle_options').show();
    $('bundle_options_background').show();
    }); 
</script>
```

I can understand that this is **jQuery conflict**.I tried several ways to add `jQuery.noConflict();` its not working.
If the **options** works fine **images are not loading** if the **images** load **Options are not working**.

Is there any other ways to load the image on scrolling the page?

I am using **magento 1.7 version**.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: add this after loading jquery <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> and change your code from $("img.lazy") to jQuery("img.lazy")

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, If i add jQuery("img.lazy") instead of $("img.lazy") its says jQuery lazyload is not a function.But i did not try adding this <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> at the end.Ill try this.i added this line before the code.

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi its not working.

Comment: did you try to change every selector to jQuery('bundle_options')

Comment: Yes,that way also not giving me the correct result.I tried this way too.
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq('bundle_options')

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34296/discussion-between-mujas-and-ahmed-el-awadi).

Comment: first you have to remove conflict from this file `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.lazyload.js?v=1.9.7'); ?>"></script>` replace $ with jQuery add `jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(); `

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a javascript conflict between jQuery and Prototype on a custom library

Comment: I have answered it and want to leave it open as this is a very common problem in Magento. Prototype = Magento, so on topic. jQuery is used by many and many have experienced the Prototype/jQuery conflict ;)

Answer (score 4):

Magento uses Prototype JS which has already claimed the `$` variable. You need to use jQuery in "no conflict" mode so jQuery won't also claim the `$` variable:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

After this, you cannot use `$()` to use jQuery, because then you call Prototype. You have to use the full name: `jQuery()`. You can change your self written scripts by:

1. Replacing all uses of `$` by `jQuery`
2. Wrap your scripts in an anonymous function passing jQuery as a parameter:

   ```
   (function($) {
        // You can simply use $ here
        $('selector').dosomething();
   })(jQuery);
   ```

The `jquery.lazyload.js` library is well written and is able to operate in both normal mode and conflict mode. There's no need to change the files of this library (replacing all uses of `$` by `jQuery`) as it is already making use of the anonymous function method, see [jquery.lazyload.js](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/blob/master/jquery.lazyload.js):

```
16.  (function($, window, document, undefined) {
17.      var $window = $(window);
18.  
19.      $.fn.lazyload = function(options) {

             // *SNIP* (lots of code...)

240.     });
241. 
242. })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Thank you @7ochem,As we have weekend in dubai unable to check your answer.Ill check this.

Answer (score 1):

For the future user i am updating the answer how i short it out this issue.
I added a no conflict like below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--ADD BELOW LINE------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<!----------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.lazyload.js?v=1.9.7'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//-----------Replaced the "$" to "jQuery_1_10_2"
    jQuery_1_10_2(function() {
      jQuery_1_10_2("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn"
      });
   });
</script>
```

And Edit the **jquery.lazyload.js**.

**Replace** `$.fn.lazyload = function(options) {`

**With**

`jQuery_1_10_2.fn.lazyload = function(options) {`

**I hope this will help to some one in future.**

Comment: Why does normal no-conflict not work? Like: `jQuery.noConflict();`. That's all. And then just use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` (not some `jQuery_1_10_2`). Because then you don't have to change the lazyload library. Or do you have multiple jQuery versions running?

Comment: I have different version in my website.i tried several ways and this way used to short out the issue.I am not clear to answer why the normal no-conflict not work for me.

Comment: Ok, one more comment: To fix lazyload, don't do it like you did now. Please change the last line of the file and replace `(jQuery, window, document)` with `(jQuery_1_10_2, window, document)`. That is the best way

Comment: If i use like this don't i need to add like this.
'jQuery_1_10_2(function() {
      jQuery_1_10_2("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn"
      });
   });'
Really thank you for your help.