# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqzoom is not a function

Tags: magento-enterprise, jquery, zoom

I am trying to add an image zoom to our Magento EE 1.14.2.1 which apparently was removed by a prior developer. So I found a script called "jqzoom" http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jqzoom which I want to use. I of course have added a call to Jquery in the head.phtml file and also added the call to the needed jqzoom js and css files in the media.phtml file. However now when I view a product detail page I see in the console the below error.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqzoom is not a function

Now on the top of my media.phtml page I have

```
<!-- Load image zoom code -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getUrl()?>skin/frontend/bronson/default/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js"></script>  

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl()?>skin/frontend/bronson/default/css/jquery.jqzoom.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {
           /* simple call */
            $('.cloud-zoom').jqzoom();


            /* more complex call*/
            /*var options = {  
              zoomType: 'standard',  
              lens:true,  
              preloadImages: true,  
              alwaysOn:false,  
              zoomWidth: 300,  
              zoomHeight: 250,  
              xOffset:90,  
              yOffset:30,  
              position:'left'  
              //...MORE OPTIONS  
           };

           $('.cloud-zoom').jqzoom(options); */

        });

  </script>
```

At the top of the jquery.jqzoom-core.js file I have

```
     jQuery.noConflict();
     (function ($) {
```

So I am not sure why the site still does not see jqzoom as a function and how to fix?

```
                        *********
```

I updated my media.phtml to the below and no my issue is I do not see any errors in the console but but the image zoom also does not work.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

then I changed the /* simple call */ to

```
jQuery('cloud-zoom').jqzoom();
```

Comment: what is you magento version

Comment: I mentioned at the top of my post my Magento version is Magento EE 1.14.2.1 :)

Comment: i also had the same issue like this this.i short it out.You can check this link which i asked on the forum and my answer too.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97200/jquery-conflict-in-the-product-view-page

Comment: update if this approach help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the dollar, you will have issues since it's `prototype`'s baby. Where you call `$(...).jqzoom();`, replace it with `jQuery(...).jqzoom();` and this should fix your issue (keep the noConflict).

Comment: thanks Mayers. I did that and now I do not get any errors however the image zoom still is not working.

Comment: At this point, this is very vague. Do you have a link we can see this on?

Comment: You can view the page here http://bit.ly/1KSxpSp I actually just changed the jquery file to be a different zoom (thinking maybe the other one had issues) so you will see calls to elevatezoom instead of jqzoom but the code layout is the same.